# I am trying to get my site to show the amount of items in the basket at the basket icon on each page

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, e-commerce

I am building an e-commerce site with node.js and using EJS also, and i'm trying to get it so that the amount in the basket shows on each page. I have this function below that works as it shows the amount on one of the pages but not other pages.

```
function getBasketItems(req, res, callback) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM basketitems WHERE customerID = ?', [req.session.username], (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            var amount = res.length;
            callback(null, amount);
        }
    })
}
```

The function works here:

```
router.get('/pens', (req, res) => {
    let title = 'Pens | Giraffe Website';
    let header = 'Pens';
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM products';
    let basketAmount = 0;
    getBasketItems(req, res, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            basketAmount = data;
        }
    });

    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        res.render('products', {
            title: title,
            header: header,
            data: result,
            username: req.session.username,
            loggedin: req.session.loggedin,
            basketAmount: basketAmount
        });
    })
});
```

But not here:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let title = 'Home | Giraffe Website';
    let basketAmount = 0;
    getBasketItems(req, res, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            basketAmount = data;
        }
    });

    res.render('index', {
        title: title,
        username: req.session.username,
        loggedin: req.session.loggedin,
        basketAmount: basketAmount
    });
})
```

Here is the GitHub Repo - https://github.com/shiney1884/giraffe-website
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the second code snippet is that is executes before the `getBasketItems` has returned a response since it executed synchronously. You can promisify `getBasketItems` as:

```js
function getBasketItems(req, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM basketitems WHERE customerID = ?', [req.session.username], (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                var amount = res.length
                resolve(amount)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

And then use it with async/await:

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let title = 'Home | Giraffe Website';
    let basketAmount = 0;
    let basketAmount = await getBasketItems(req, res)

    res.render('index', {
        title: title,
        username: req.session.username,
        loggedin: req.session.loggedin,
        basketAmount: basketAmount
    });
})
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! This works. I gave asynchrounous functions a go the last time I tried to get this to work and wasn't able to do it properly. I need to study this.

Comment: Sounds great. Please accept the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it works in the first case, as long as there are more then one connection to a DB, is a pure luck.
In order to get around this problem (and similar in the future) I think it would be good for you to first understand a concept of Javascript and asynchronous operations.

The basic tutorial can be found here https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-callback/
Going through that, just imagine that `setTimeout` is a `db.query`.

Comment: In the first case, you have 2 async operations `getBasketItems` and `db.query` but `render` is called when we are sure that only `db.query` finished. If by any chance `getBasketItems` finishes after `db.query` then `basketAmount` will not be set.